# How Can I integrate TestRail with C# correctly

Tags: c#, nunit, test-runner, testrail

I'm trying to integrate my automation tests with TestRail. I work with c#.
I use the API of TestRail in my test project. I create TestRun manually and have testRun id and test case id.
I have a problem when my test case is located in nested directories(in som test suites tree) not in the root of testSuites.
Returned error message is:

> **TearDown : AutomationSport.Tests.TestRail.TestRailAPIException : TestRail API returned HTTP 400 ("No (active) test found for the
> run/case combination.")**

But when my test case is in root directory, testrail integration works correctly and it set test case status in TesrRail correctly.
How should I get a test case id in that case?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm not in the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a correct solution. To be able to add a test result to the TestRail run, you need to include the case to the run.
You can do it in two ways:

1. `POST index.php?/api/v2/update_run/{run_id}` with the body:

   {
   "include_all": false,
   "case_ids": [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
   }

But take into account that only `case_ids` will be included, if you had some tests in the run before - they will be excluded.

2. `POST index.php?/api/v2/update_run/{run_id`} with the body:

   {
   "include_all": true
   }

In this case all cases from the suite will be included.